# Find if string is MySQL function in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, joomla, joomla-dbo

I have a function that takes an array and creates a SQL statement based on they key/value pairs of the array.  For example:

```
 name=>SomeKittens
```

It'd turn into

```
(`name`) VALUES ('SomeKittens')
```

The only problem is when I use a MySQL string function such as `NOW()`.

```
creation_date=>NOW()
```

turns into

```
(`creation_date`) VALUES ('NOW()')
```

Note that `NOW()` is escaped.  Is there any way to detect if the value is a MySQL string function?  (besides of course `$value === "NOW()"`)

I'm using the Joomla DBO but am open to PDO/MySQLi solutions as well.

([relevant chat discussion](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/4657210#4657210))

Comment: `NOW()` isn't escaped, but it is a literal string.

Comment: How do you distinguish between `NOW()` intended to be a function, and `NOW()` intended to be a hard-coded 5-character literal string?  You may need to manually provide more metadata in your key/value pairs to indicate how to interpret the value, e.g., `name=>STRING:SomeKittens` and `creation_date=>FUNC:NOW()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you allow functions with arguments I don't think you will be able to protect your db against SQL injections.
If you allow only functions w/o arguments (like NOW()) you might as well hardcode a list.

Answer (score 1):

You may simply want to define a constant like MYSQL_NOW that when creating your query you know to convert to a NOW() function call rather than 'NOW()' string.